# how can I install apps from browser?

Tags: software-installation, multipass

I downloaded it, but I can't activate it. It looks like this...
[image: look]
[image: error]

Answer (score 4):

You can't install software in Ubuntu using *.exe* files. You will have to download the *.deb* file.

If you want multipass, you can get it by running `sudo snap install multipass --classic` in the terminal.

Usually, software are installed in Ubuntu through the terminal using repositories or through the Ubuntu Software Store.

See https://multipass.run/, https://snapcraft.io/multipass and https://multipass.run/docs/installing-on-linux

Comment: error: snap "multipass" is not available on edge for this architecture (i386)
       but exists on other architectures (amd64, arm64, armhf).

Comment: it is showed...

Comment: @mech_boy_ Which command did you use?

Answer (score 0):

from the image it seems that you have downloaded a windows program (it's file extension is ".exe" and there is "win64" in the file name).
There are a few things that you can try to get the program running under Linux:

1. look for a Linux version of the program:

   - I am not certain whether this is the program that you are looking for, but there seems to be a snap available either by typing `sudo snap install multipass` in a terminal, or searching for it in the software center
   - OR There might be a ".deb" file available on the program's website which you can install via `sudo dpkg -i [filename].deb`
2. if there isn't a Linux version of the program you can still run the program via Wine

   - So far I haven't tried this myself, but you should be able to find plenty of tutorials on how to use wine to run windows programs on linux https://www.winehq.org/